# Parsing dl with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, asp.net, screen-scraping, html-agility-pack

This is the sample HTML I am trying to parse with Html Agility Pack in ASP.Net (C#).

```
<div class="content-div">
    <dl>
        <dt>
            <b><a href="1.html" title="1">1</a></b>
        </dt>
        <dd> First Entry</dd>
        <dt>
            <b><a href="2.html" title="2">2</a></b>
        </dt>
        <dd> Second Entry</dd>
        <dt>
            <b><a href="3.html" title="3">3</a></b>
        </dt>
        <dd> Third Entry</dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

The Values I want are :

- The hyperlink -> 1.html
- The Anchor Text ->1
- Inner Text od dd -> First Entry

(I have taken examples of the first entry here but I want the values for these elements for all the entries in the list )

This is the code I am using currently,

```
var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
            var document = webGet.Load(url2);
var parsedValues=
   from info in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='content-div']")
   from content in info.SelectNodes("dl//dd")
   from link in info.SelectNodes("dl//dt/b/a")
       .Where(x => x.Attributes.Contains("href"))
   select new 
   {
       Text = content.InnerText,
       Url = link.Attributes["href"].Value,
       AnchorText = link.InnerText,
   };

GridView1.DataSource = parsedValues;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

The problem is that I get the values for the link and the anchor text correctly but for the inner text of  it just takes the value of the first entry and fills the same value for all other entries for the total number of times the element occurs and then it starts over with the second one. I may not be so clear in my explanation so here's a sample output I am getting with this code:

```
First Entry     1.html  1
First Entry     2.html  2
First Entry     3.html  3
Second Entry    1.html  1
Second Entry    2.html  2
Second Entry    3.html  3
Third Entry     1.html  1
Third Entry     2.html  2
Third Entry     3.html  3
```

Whereas I am trying to get

```
First Entry      1.html     1
Second Entry     2.html     2
Third Entry      3.html     3
```

I am pretty new to HAP and have very little knoweledge on xpath, so I am sure I am doing something wrong here, but I couldn't make it work even after spending hours on it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution 1**

I have defined a function that given a `dt` node will return the next `dd` node after it:

```
private static HtmlNode GetNextDDSibling(HtmlNode dtElement)
{
    var currentNode = dtElement;

    while (currentNode != null)
    {
        currentNode = currentNode.NextSibling;

        if(currentNode.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Element && currentNode.Name =="dd")
            return currentNode;
    }

    return null;
}
```

and now the LINQ code can be transformed to:

```
var parsedValues =
    from info in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='content-div']")
    from dtElement in info.SelectNodes("dl/dt")
    let link = dtElement.SelectSingleNode("b/a[@href]")
    let ddElement = GetNextDDSibling(dtElement)
    where link != null && ddElement != null
    select new
    {
        Text = ddElement.InnerHtml,
        Url = link.GetAttributeValue("href", ""),
        AnchorText = link.InnerText
    };
```

**Solution 2**

Without additional functions:

```
var infoNode = 
        document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='content-div']");

var dts = infoNode.SelectNodes("dl/dt");
var dds = infoNode.SelectNodes("dl/dd");

var parsedValues = dts.Zip(dds,
    (dt, dd) => new
    {
        Text = dd.InnerHtml,
        Url = dt.SelectSingleNode("b/a[@href]").GetAttributeValue("href", ""),
        AnchorText = dt.SelectSingleNode("b/a[@href]").InnerText
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works. However I don't exactly understand what's going on here. Can it be done without a function, using some kind of xpath/regex? This solution is perfectly fine for me, I am just curious how it works. It will be nice if you can give a brief explanation, thanks.

Comment: The problem is that we need something like "given this `dt` tag, give me the `dd` tag that comes immediately after it". I tried to make it simpler, by selecting the ddElement as being dtElement.NextSibling, but HtmlAgilityPack considers the next node to be the whitespace between the `<dt>` and `<dd>` tags. This led me to the slightly uglier solution that you see above.

Comment: I just figured out another possible solution that does not involve declaring a function - please see the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, I get it now. I tried your second solution too, but I am getting an error (below:), is there any references to be added for the second solution to work. Error : 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Zip' and no extension method 'Zip' accepting a first argument of type 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Zip is a Linq extension function. What .Net version are you using?

Comment: `Zip` is only supported in 4.0. You could, however, use this implementation by Jon Skeet: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/14/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-35-zip.aspx.

Answer (score 2):

Just a e.g. of how can you parse some elements using `Html Agility Pack`

```
public string ParseHtml()
{
    string output = null;
    HtmlDocument htmldocument = new HtmlDocument();
    htmldocument.LoadHtml(YourHTML);

    HtmlNode node = htmldocument.DocumentNode;    

    HtmlNodeCollection dds = node.SelectNodes("//dd"); //Select all dd tags
    HtmlNodeCollection anchors = node.SelectNodes("//b/a[@href]"); //Select all 'a' tags that contais href attribute

    for (int i = 0; i < dds.Count; i++)
    {
        string atributteValue = null.
        Text = dds[i].InnerText;
        Url = anchors[i].GetAttributeValue("href", atributteValue);
        AnchorText = anchors[i].InnerText;

        //Your code...
    }
    return output;
}
```