# How to display video from xml file?

Tags: linq, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, xml-parsing

Hi am using xml file given below,how can i get videos from xml file?

```
<Category name="Videos">
   <article articleid="68">
     <videourl>
      <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/52375409?fullscreen=0" width="500"   height="298" frameborder="0"></iframe>
     </videourl>
    </article>
</Category>
```

My Code is

```
XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load("CountriesXML.xml");

        var data = from query in loadedData.Descendants("Country")
          select new CountryData
          {
             url = (string)query.Element("videourl").Elements("iframe").Single().Attribute("src").Value,
          };
     countryList = data.ToList();
```

but i got NullReferenceException error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load("CountriesXML.xml");
var videos = from f in xdoc.Descendants("iframe")
             select new {
                Src = (string)f.Attribute("src"),
                Width = (int)f.Attribute("width"),
                Height = (int)f.Attribute("height")
             };
```

Or with your updated code:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load("CountriesXML.xml");
var data = from c in xdoc.Descendants("Category") // you have Category element
           select new CountryData {
              url = (string)c.Element("article") // there is also article element
                             .Element("videourl")
                             .Elements("iframe")
                             .Single().Attribute("src")
           };
```

Comment: Hi how can parse html file in windows phone 7?please help me some one.

Comment: @user123 I use HtmlAgilityPack for parsing html

Comment: ya i know that, but i dont know how can i use htmlagilitypack with linq

Comment: @user take a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942595/parsing-html-with-htmlagilitypack

Comment: @user123 sorry, I will be busy few hours. Either wait, or ask another question about html parsing :)

Comment: @user123 I'm back :) Parsing with HtmlAgilityPack should look like `var urls = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//iframe/@src");`

Comment: am not asking like this question.please look on [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338089/how-can-i-parse-html-file-in-windows-phone-7?]