# How can i parse html file in windows phone 7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, linq-to-xml, html-parsing

Hi am using xml file given below,i want to parse html file .

```
<Description>
 <Fullcontent>
   <div id="container" class="cf">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dev2.mercuryminds.com/imageslider/css/demo.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <ul class="slides">
            <li>Sonam Kapoor<img src="http://deys.jpeg"/></li>
            <li>Amithab<img src="http://deysAmithab.jpeg"/></li>
            <li>sridevi<img src="http://deyssridevi.jpeg"/></li>
            <li>anil-kapoor<img src="http://deysanil-kapoor.jpeg"/></li>
         </ul>
    </div>
  </Fullcontent>
</Description>
```

i want bind image with name

Comment: i was installed HtmlAgilityPack and tried some coding i cant get.

Comment: Show the code snippet that you're using to attempt to parse it with `HtmlAgilityPack`.

Comment: how to add HtmlAgilityPack? i cant add references, i got error like HtmlAgilityPack.dll because it was not built using the windows phone runtime.windows phone projects will work only with the windows phone assemblies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install *HtmlAgilityPack* from NuGet (just search for agility). Parsing is also simple. Here is way for selecting image tags and taking source attributes:

```
HtmlDocument html = new HtmlDocument();
html.Load(path_to_file);
var urls = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul[@class='slides']/li/img")
                            .Select(node => node.Attributes["src"].Value);
```

Btw looks like direct selection of attributes is [not supported yet](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/discussions/204342?ProjectName=htmlagilitypack).

Comment: Hi how can i add htmlagilitypack in project? if i add reference i got some error

Comment: @user123 try to uninstall it and then add from nuget again. Btw which some error do you get?